# Recursive Function With Increasing Values

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration, corecursion

I am trying to write a recursive function the evaluate for n

```
3(2+1)+4(3+2+1)+...+(n+1)(n+...+2+1)
```

I know that in general we need to write it as induction the result for the base case let say n=1 and then call the function for n-1 which will end up in the base case.

But in the following function the elements increases, how should I approach this

Comment: This simplifies to a polynomial of degree 4, so no recursion is needed. From wolfram alpha: `sum_(i=2)^n (i + 1) sum_(j=1)^i j = 1/24 (3 n^4 + 14 n^3 + 21 n^2 + 10 n - 48)`

Comment: @PaulHankin would you please share the process of simplification (maybe in an answer)? I can't get it (or seem to produce the steps on wolfram :)

Comment: `j+...+3+2+1` is `j(j+1)/2` and then multiplying by `j+1` gives you a 3rd order poly. Then you just need to apply the formulas for `sum(j)`, `sum(j^2)` and `sum(j^3)` (perhaps subtracting a term for j=1 which is missing in the overall result.

Comment: @PaulHankin thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is also the same as the general way you mentioned. just look at it this way:

(n+1)(n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1) + (n)((n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1) + (n-1)((n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 1)

so assume you have a function named SumTo(n), which return sum of all numbers starting at 1 up to n, this is the recursive function :

```
int Calc(n)
{
   if (n == 3)
     return n(sumTo(2));

   else return n(sumTo(n-1)) * Calc(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You  will just need to maintain your loop variables and a counter, increasing the counter on each iteration until it equals the `n`, starting from `n = 0` case (or 1, whatever).

Then when `count == n` you have your answer, so you end the loop.

Counting up instead of down is characteristic of *corecursion*, provided that each iteration step is *finite* (here, it certainly is).